# Почему программа без причин прекращает работу?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi

Здравствуйте!

Я написал программу на Visual Studio C++ 2008. При работе в ОС Windows 
она без видимых причин через некоторое время прекращает свою работу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Answer (score 3):

Мейби, это консольное приложение на С++, и прога закрывается, когда выполнится весь код, а тебе нужно, чтоб не закрывалась без определённых действий?

Если так, то в конце функции `main` добавьте `_getch();`, а сверху подключите `#include "conio.h"`
Ну а если это C#, то `Console.ReadKey();` в помощь

Comment: Пожалуйста, воздержитесь от гадания на кофейной гуще, и попросите автора вопроса привести необходимые подробности.

Comment: Хоть и гадание, но автор ответа почти наверняка прав :)